# primes of the form $p = x^2 + ny^2$: primitive element for the Hilbert class field of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-n})$ is a real algebraic integer?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

The following proposition is found in $\S 5$ of *Primes of the form $p = x^2 + ny^2$: Fermat, Class Field Theory, and Complex Multiplication* by David A. Cox:

**Proposition 5.29**. Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field and let $L$ be a finite extension of $K$ which is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then

(i) There is a real algebraic integer $\alpha$ such that $L = K(\alpha)$.

(ii) Let $\alpha$ be as in (i) and $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ denote its minimal polynomial. If $p$ is a prime not dividing the discriminant of $f(x)$, then
$$
p\text{ splits completely in } L \Leftrightarrow
\cases{(d_K/p) = 1 \text{ and } f(x) \equiv 0\bmod{p}\cr
\text{has an integer solution.}
}
$$
My trouble concerns (i). In his proof Cox uses the fact that $[L \cap \mathbb{R} : \mathbb{Q}] = [L : K] < \infty$ to conclude there exists $\alpha \in \mathscr{O}_L \cap \mathbb{R}$ such that $L \cap \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

The Primitive Element Theorem guarantees the existence of $\alpha \in L \cap \mathbb{R}$ such that $L \cap \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, but I do not understand how we are able to select $\alpha$ so that $\alpha \in \mathscr{O}_L$. Perhaps I am missing something obvious?

Comment: in the first edition, this is Proposition 5.29; the step you dislike refers to Exercise 5.19 a few pages later

Comment: @WillJagy Cox refers to exercise 5.19 in his proof. The relevant part is (ii), which states For $\alpha \in L \cap \mathbb{R}$, $L \cap \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \Leftrightarrow L = K(\alpha)$. He uses this and the Primitive Element Theorem to establish $L = K(\alpha)$ under the assumption $[L : K] < \infty$.

There is nothing about $\alpha \in \mathscr{O}_L$ in exercise 5.19, which can be solved without establishing this stronger claim.

Comment: Multiply $\alpha$ by a suitably chosen rational integer.

Answer (score 1):

I *was* missing something obvious. Following the suggestion of @franzlemmermeyer, I found the following proposition in Chapter 2 of J. S. Milne's course notes for [Algebraic Number Theory](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ant.html):

Let $A$ be an integral domain and $L$ be a field containing $A$. Then we have

**Proposition 2.6**. Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$ and let $L$ be a field containing $K$. If $\alpha \in L$ is algebraic over $K$, then there exists a $d \in A$ such that $d\alpha$ is integral over $A$.

Taking $A = \mathbb{Z}$, $K = \mathbb{Q}$, and $L \cap \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ the field containing $K$ allows us to select $\alpha \in \mathscr{O}_L \cap \mathbb{R}$.